# Nokogiri css don’t find element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I`m have a problem in Nokogiri. Here is my XML:

```
<nfeProc>
  <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <infNFe Id="NFe123" versao="3.10">
      <ide>
        <name>25</name>
      </ide>
    </infNFe>
  </NFe>
</nfeProc>
```

I want find the `ide` tag, but just `nfeProc` tag can be found.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("sample.xml"))
doc.css('ide')
=> []
```

But, when I add an attribute to `nfeProc` tag, work nice.

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <infNFe Id="NFe123" versao="3.10">
      <ide>
        <name>25</name>
      </ide>
    </infNFe>
  </NFe>
</nfeProc>

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("sample.xml"))
doc.css('ide')
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x19226c4 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Ele...
```

What should I do to it works without `xmlns` attribute?

Comment: please try according to https://coderwall.com/p/03r98q/using-the-nokogiri-gem-to-parse-nested-xml-data-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about the namespace `Nokogiri::XML::Document` provides a method for that called `remove_namespaces!`.

```
doc = <<XML
<nfeProc>
  <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <infNFe Id="NFe123" versao="3.10">
      <ide>
        <name>25</name>
      </ide>
    </infNFe>
  </NFe>
</nfeProc>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(doc)
doc.remove_namespaces!
doc.css('ide name').text
#=> "25"
```